# Python source code for built-in "in" operator

Tags: python, c, string, cpython, python-internals

I am trying to find the implementation of the built-in `in` operator in the (C) Python source code. I have searched in the built-in functions source code, [bltinmodule.c](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c), but cannot find the implementation of this operator. Where can I find this implementation?

My goal is to improve the sub-string search in Python by extending different C implementations of this search, although I am not sure if Python already uses the idea I have.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To find the implementation of *any* python operator, first find out what bytecode Python generates for it, using the [`dis.dis` function](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
>>> dis.dis("'0' in ()")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('0')
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (())
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `in` operator becomes a `COMPARE_OP` byte code. Now you can trace how this opcode is being handled in the Python evaluation loop in [`Python/ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07fbbfde1b300369b4f8d1cfb80045fbb23b7091/Python/ceval.c#L2673-L2684):

```c
TARGET(COMPARE_OP)
    PyObject *right = POP();
    PyObject *left = TOP();
    PyObject *res = cmp_outcome(oparg, left, right);
    Py_DECREF(left);
    Py_DECREF(right);
    SET_TOP(res);
    if (res == NULL)
        goto error;
    PREDICT(POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE);
    PREDICT(POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE);
    DISPATCH();
```

`cmp_outcome()` is [defined in the same file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07fbbfde1b300369b4f8d1cfb80045fbb23b7091/Python/ceval.c#L4726-L4776), and the `in` operator is one of the switches:

```
case PyCmp_IN:
    res = PySequence_Contains(w, v);
    if (res < 0)
         return NULL;
    break;
```

A quick grep shows us where `PySequence_Contains` is defined, in [Objects/abstract.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07fbbfde1b300369b4f8d1cfb80045fbb23b7091/Objects/abstract.c#L2057-L2069):

```
int
PySequence_Contains(PyObject *seq, PyObject *ob)
{
    Py_ssize_t result;
    PySequenceMethods *sqm = seq->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
    if (sqm != NULL && sqm->sq_contains != NULL)
        return (*sqm->sq_contains)(seq, ob);
    result = _PySequence_IterSearch(seq, ob, PY_ITERSEARCH_CONTAINS);
    return Py_SAFE_DOWNCAST(result, Py_ssize_t, int);
}
```

`PySequence_Contains` thus uses the [`sq_contains` slot on the Sequence object structure](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#PySequenceMethods.sq_contains) or an iterative search otherwise, for Python C objects.

For Python 3 Unicode string objects, this slot is implemented as [`PyUnicode_Contains` in Objects/unicodeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07fbbfde1b300369b4f8d1cfb80045fbb23b7091/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11135-L11193), in Python 2 you also want to check out [`string_contains` in Objects/stringobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6a336f6484a13c01516b6bfc3b767075cc2cb4f7/Objects/stringobject.c#L1149-L1166). Basically just grep for `sq_contains` in the Objects/ subdirectory for the various implementations by the different Python types.

For generic python objects, it's interesting to note that [Objects/typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07fbbfde1b300369b4f8d1cfb80045fbb23b7091/Objects/typeobject.c#L6110-L6140) defers this to the `__contains__` method on custom classes, if so defined.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: i went through the code of string contains for python 2.7, it uses PyUnicode_Contains that uses [stringlib_contains_obj] (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2370e331241b/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l6223), that uses [stringlib_find] (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2370e331241b/Objects/stringlib/find.h#l85) that uses [fastsearch] (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2370e331241b/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#l37) that compares only the first letter of the substring, something is wrong their or i am missing something (and it doesn't use Boyer–Moore as i thought)?

Comment: @Michael: It doesn't use Boyer-Moore, it uses an algorithm *inspired* by B-M, see http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm. It's simplified B-M with some Horspool and Sunday thrown in.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.9, the bytecode `COMPARE_OP` was split into four distinct instructions, and `CONTAINS_OP` for 'in' and 'not in' tests.

That did not change the implementation of `in` operator,  it's directly handled in [Python/ceval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/de2c91a89aa0e89d5d01d71697d0f27a9f60c11d/Python/ceval.c#L3033), calling `PySequence_Contains()`.

- Doc: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Doc/whatsnew/3.9.rst#cpython-bytecode-changes
- Related issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue39156