# Functionality of Python `in` vs. `__contains__`

Tags: python, python-2.7, contains

I implemented the `__contains__` method on a class for the first time the other day, and the behavior wasn't what I expected. I suspect there's some subtlety to the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) operator that I don't understand and I was hoping someone could enlighten me.

It appears to me that the `in` operator doesn't simply wrap an object's `__contains__` method, but it also attempts to coerce the output of `__contains__` to boolean. For example, consider the class

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __contains__(self, val):
        # Don't perform comparison, just return a list as
        # an example.
        return [False, False]
```

The `in` operator and a direct call to the `__contains__` method return very different output:

```
>>> dum = Dummy()
>>> 7 in dum
True
>>> dum.__contains__(7)
[False, False]
```

Again, it looks like `in` is calling `__contains__` but then coercing the result to `bool`. I can't find this behavior documented anywhere except for the fact that the `__contains__` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) says `__contains__` should only ever return `True` or `False`.

I'm happy following the convention, but can someone tell me the precise relationship between `in` and `__contains__`?

## Epilogue

I decided to choose @eli-korvigo answer, but everyone should look at @ashwini-chaudhary [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542543/functionality-of-python-in-vs-contains/38542777?noredirect=1#comment64477339_38542543) about the [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue16011), below.

Comment: Because your contains-method returns equivalent of bool([False, False])

Comment: Related bug: [`in` should be consistent with return value of `__contains__`](https://bugs.python.org/issue16011)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Can you write this comment up as an answer? Just a one-liner or so is fine. I had never seen this bug report and it precisely answers my question. I don't so much care about the specific implementation of `in` as I care about the design reasoning and apparent lack of documentaiton. If you post this answer, I will select your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the source, Luke!

Let's trace down the `in` operator implementation

```
>>> import dis
>>> class test(object):
...     def __contains__(self, other):
...         return True

>>> def in_():
...     return 1 in test()

>>> dis.dis(in_)
    2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
                3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (test)
                6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
                9 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
               12 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the `in` operator becomes the `COMPARE_OP` virtual machine instruction. You can find that in [ceval.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/ceval.c)

```
TARGET(COMPARE_OP)
    w = POP();
    v = TOP();
    x = cmp_outcome(oparg, v, w);
    Py_DECREF(v);
    Py_DECREF(w);
    SET_TOP(x);
    if (x == NULL) break;
    PREDICT(POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE);
    PREDICT(POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE);
    DISPATCH();
```

Take a look at one of the switches in `cmp_outcome()`

```
case PyCmp_IN:
    res = PySequence_Contains(w, v);
    if (res < 0)
         return NULL;
    break;
```

Here we have the `PySequence_Contains` call

```
int
PySequence_Contains(PyObject *seq, PyObject *ob)
{
    Py_ssize_t result;
    PySequenceMethods *sqm = seq->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
    if (sqm != NULL && sqm->sq_contains != NULL)
        return (*sqm->sq_contains)(seq, ob);
    result = _PySequence_IterSearch(seq, ob, PY_ITERSEARCH_CONTAINS);
    return Py_SAFE_DOWNCAST(result, Py_ssize_t, int);
}
```

That always returns an `int` (a boolean).

P.S.

Thanks to Martijn Pieters for providing the [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244378/3846213) to find the implementation of the `in` operator.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but I was looking for more of the reasoning behind the design and apparent lack of documentation than the implementation of `in`. I'm upvoting your answer anyway because it is useful info.

Comment: @joshua.r.smith I guess, in this case the implementation is directly related to the reasoning. Basically, this is how Python-C API was conceived. As for the lack of documentation, the docs don't really reference `True` or `False`, they only say that `__cointains__`  should return something either true or false (i.e. that can be evaluated as `True` or `False`). You can see throughout the docs, that they explicitly use `True` and `False` where important. Anyway, they could've written it less ambiguously, so you can file a documentation patch report.

Answer (score 8):

In [Python reference for `__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) it's written that `__contains__` should return `True` or `False`.

If the return value is not boolean it's converted to boolean. Here is proof:

```
class MyValue:
    def __bool__(self):
        print("__bool__ function ran")
        return True

class Dummy:
    def __contains__(self, val):
        return MyValue()
```

Now write in shell:

```
>>> dum = Dummy()
>>> 7 in dum
__bool__ function ran
True
```

And `bool()` of nonempty list returns `True`.

**Edit:**

It's only documentation for `__contains__`, if you really want to see precise relation you should consider looking into source code although I'm not sure where exactly, but it's already answered. In [documentation for comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) it's written:

> However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an `if` statement), Python will call [bool()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

So you can guess that it's similar with `__contains__`.

Comment: I think `"__bool__ function runned"` should be `"__bool__ function ran"`

Answer (score -3):

This is for anyone who is reading this to understand which one to use, I would say use `__contains__()` instead of in, since it is **faster**.

For checking this, I did a simple experiment.

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
q = 'abababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababababc'

print(q.__contains__('c'))
#print('c' in q)
endTime = time.time()
deltaTime = endTime - startTime
print(deltaTime)
```

For one iteration, I commented the in and other time, I commented `__contains__`. Here are the results:

```
(Using in)
PS C:\Users\username> & python c:/Users/username/containsvsin.py
True
0.0009970664978027344
(Using __contains__)
PS C:\Users\username> & python c:/Users/username/Downloads/containsvsin.py
True
0.0
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.