# How does "contains" work? Does it use iter and getitem?

Tags: python

How does `__contains__` work? For example I have a class `MyClass` and an instance of this class called `a`, when I write `if val in a:` I'm basically invoking `__contains__`, from my understanding, if `__contains__` is not implemented in the class then `__iter__` is invoked, which iterates between the list returned by `__getitem__` (which in my example is implemented in the class) and if val is equal to some element of the list then `__contains__` returns True. Is it right?

**EDIT**: `__getitem__` in my code only returns the element of the list at a given position so I don't know how would that work together with `__iter__`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542543/functionality-of-python-in-vs-contains/38542777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) document is clear enough,

```
> Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if
> item is in self, false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should
> consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the
> key-item pairs.
> 
> For objects that don’t define __contains__(), the membership test
> first tries iteration via __iter__(), then the old sequence iteration
> protocol via __getitem__(), see this section in the language
> reference.
```

Comment: "Should return true if item is in self" so it checks every attribute of the instance of the class and if it finds that one attribute has the value "val" then it returns true?

Comment: i don't think it will check object attributes (or it's dictionary).   (x.a) x has a attribute a, does not mean `a in x`.

Comment: roughly `in` is only meaningful (defined) when the object can be considered as a container class (dict, sequence etc).

Comment: by dictionary i mean [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right. More specifics [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For user-defined classes which define the **contains**() method, x in
> y returns True if y.**contains**(x) returns a true value, and False
> otherwise.
>
> For user-defined classes which do not define **contains**() but do
> define **iter**(), x in y is True if some value z, for which the
> expression x is z or x == z is true, is produced while iterating over
> y. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in
> raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines
> **getitem**(), x in y is True if and only if there is a non-negative integer index i such that x is y[i] or x == y[i], and no lower integer
> index raises the IndexError exception. (If any other exception is
> raised, it is as if in raised that exception).

Comment: if only "__getitem__" is implemented, when i invoke "__contains__", does it also use "__len__" to know the maximum index possible? otherwise, i don't know how the program would stop

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to with the 'because "you" wrote "true" '. However, I was not trying to plagiarize or claim the information, but rather lay out the information here from the docs. The link was not included properly. It's there now.

Comment: I see. Well, I do say true/false in all my writing. But thanks for pointing this out – I'll be sure to make sure everything is properly credited going forward.