# How is python keyword 'in' written

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I know the time complexity of the 'in' operator for lists has a time complexity of O(n). I was wondering what the does code or logic for the operator looks like.

Comment: Well…you probably compare the first item of the sequence to the target, then the second, etc. until you find a match then stop and return True. If you get to the end without a match, you return False. This means that in the worst case you make `n` comparisons for a sequence with `n` items.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244074/python-source-code-for-built-in-in-operator

Comment: In general, objects can define the ``__contains__(self, thing)`` method to implement a custom ``in`` test. However for the builtin objects (list, dict, set) it is probably hardcoded in C code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.